# PHP and Javascript picture gallery challenge - modal doesn't show correct images

Tags: javascript, php, photo, image-gallery

While I am not too bad with PHP, Javascript to me is kind of a strange looking PHP, and it often seems to mirror this approach back to me. It behaves strangely, and I don't know why. So please forgive my lack of real knowledge.

I am programming a picture gallery, using PHP as well as Javascript. It works well if there is only one picture gallery on the site: http://pilgrimstudio.ch/

But when there is a second gallery on the same site, the modal doesn't work. I have tried out various things, but nothing worked - I ended up with different kinds of strange behavior. It seems that Javascript is not addressing the pictures properly, but I don't see why. Here is the current kind of strange: http://pilgrimstudio.ch/News (the modal only shows one - the first - picture, and no thumbnails, and the navigation functionality doesn't work).

Here is the code:

```html
<?php

// THIS IS ON THE SITE

$id = 1;

$images = array();
$images[] = array("C37AC30Harmonia/C37.jpg"=>"Die Studer C 37 R&ouml;hren Bandmaschine");
$images[] = array("C37AC30Harmonia/Harmonia.jpg"=>"Zwei der drei neuen Harmonia");
$images[] = array("C37AC30Harmonia/PumpHarmonium.jpg"=>"Das sehr seltene Pump-Harmonium");

three_images_row($images, $id);
$id++;

// THE FOLLOWING IS IN FUNCTIONS.INC.PHP

function three_images_row($images3row, $id) {

// MAIN PAGE PICTURE TABLE

 echo '<table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
 <tr> ';
 
 $number = 1;
 $position = array("left", "center", "right");
 $position_number = 0;

 foreach($images3row AS $index => $value) {

  foreach($value AS $pic => $desc) {

   echo '
   <td>
   <div align="'.$position[$position_number].'">
   <img class = "img_3" src="../images/'.$pic.'" title="'.$desc.'" onclick="openModal'.$id.'();currentSlide'.$id.'('.$number.')">
   </div>
   </td>';

   $number++;
   $position_number++;
   
   if ($position_number == 3) {
    
    echo '</tr><tr>';
    $position_number = 0;
   }
  }
 }

 echo '</tr>
 </table>';

// MODAL

 echo '<div id="myModal'.$id.'" class="modal">
 <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal'.$id.'()">&times;</span>
 <div class="modal-content">';

 $number = 1;
 $count = count($images3row);

// Main picture in modal

 foreach($images3row AS $index => $value) {

  foreach($value AS $pic => $desc) {
  
   echo '<div class="mySlides'.$id.'">
   <!--<div class="numbertext">'.$number.' / '.$count.'</div>-->
   <img src="../images/'.$pic.'" style="width:100%">
   </div>';
   $number++;
  }
 }

// Navigation in modal

 echo '<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
 <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>';

// Caption (= description)

 echo '<div class="caption-container">
 <p id="caption'.$id.'"></p>
 </div>';
 
// Column (= thumbnails)

 echo '<div class="column-container">';

 $number = 1;

 foreach($images3row AS $index => $value) {

  foreach($value AS $pic => $desc) {

   echo' <div class="column">
   <img class="demo'.$id.' cursor" src="../images/'.$pic.'" onclick="currentSlide'.$id.'('.$number.')" alt="'.$desc.'">
   </div>';
   $number++;
  }
 }

 echo '</div>
 </div>
 </div>';
 
 ?>
 
 <script>
 function openModal<?php echo $id?>() {
   document.getElementById('myModal<?php echo $id?>').style.display = "block";
 }

 function closeModal<?php echo $id?>() {
   document.getElementById('myModal<?php echo $id?>').style.display = "none";
 }

 function currentSlide<?php echo $id?>(n) {
   showSlides(slideIndex = n);
 }
 
 var slideIndex = 1;
 showSlides(slideIndex);

 function showSlides(n) {
   var i;
   var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides<?php echo $id?>");
   var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo<?php echo $id?>");
   var captionText = document.getElementById("caption<?php echo $id?>");
   if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
   if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
   for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
       dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
   }
   slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
   dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
   captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
 }
 </script>
 
 <?php
}
  
?>
 <script>
 function plusSlides(n) {
   showSlides(slideIndex += n);
 }
 </script>
```

I guess the reason why I put several of the javascript functions into the PHP function had to do with trying to establish the correct referencing of the pictures (but I don't recall all variations I tried out). And I obviously wasn't successful with that, either. Maybe the whole code is flawed, and it can be done much better?

I am thankful for any help! And again, sorry for the dilletantic Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Need a `plusSlides()` function for both modals. Currently they
 are both calling the same one causing the modal1 image links to display modal 2 images which are not on screen.

Suggest changing this section to:

```
// Navigation in modal

echo '<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides".$id."(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides".$id."(1)">&#10095;</a>';
```

Then change this section to:

```
function currentSlide<?php echo $id?>(n) {
  showSlides<?php echo $id?>(slideIndex = n);
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides<?php echo $id?>(slideIndex);

function showSlides<?php echo $id?>(n) {
  var i;
```

And update the plusSlides function (not pictured in your code) to this:

```
function plusSlides1(n) {
  showSlides1(slideIndex += n);
}
function plusSlides2(n) {
  showSlides2(slideIndex += n);
}
```

Maybe bring the `plusSlides1(n)` and `plusSlides2(n)` functions into the php code to render them dynamically with the others?

Comment: Wow, please forgive my late reply! I just now saw all these great replies, for which I will need some time to read and comprehend. Thank you very much for them! I was under the impression that I will be informed by e-mail if someone replies, which was obviously not the case. I obviously have to change my settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your design concept, as a programmer, are a little not optimised, if I may say so :)

In js, as in other languages, the idea of `function` beside the code encapsulation, is to be reused or used more than once. You are creating functions that are doing same thing for potentially different ids. So I would make the id itself a parameter:

```
function openModal(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
function closeModal(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(n);
}
```

Obviously the image code will look something like:

```
<img class = "img_3" src="../images/'.$pic.'" title="'.$desc.'" onclick="openModal(\'myModal'.$id.'\');currentSlide('.$number.')">
```

But this is just to make what you have work.

A better approach would be to send from php only the data (the array with images and captions) and build the user interface on the client side.
Think that all thse elemnets you are using, table cells, divs, images can be easily created in js with:

```
td = document.createEelement('tr') // or td or div or img
```

html content can set with:

```
td.innerHTML = "<div><img src='...' ></div>";
```

So using js you may build easiy the UI you need:

```js
var url = "http://pilgrimstudio.ch/images/",
  images = [
    ["Studio_Bilder_Pele/Recording_1.png", "Der Aufnahmeraum 2"],
    ["Studio_Bilder_Pele/Regie_1.png", "Regie 1 früher"],
    ["2016-02-01%2015.36.22.jpg", "Regie 1"],
    ["Studio_Bilder_Pele/Regie_2.png", "Regie 2"]
  ];

function buildSlide(id, images) {
  var tr, s = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      tr = document.createElement('tr');
      document.getElementById(id).appendChild(tr);
    }
    tr.innerHTML += `<td><img width="200" src="${url+images[i][0]}"</td>`;
  }

}
buildSlide('gal1', images);
```

```css
td img {
  height: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table id="gal1">
</table>
```

This way you can separate server side code from client side code and that might help you keep things a little more clear.